# WCF Service page does not appear, but help page works

Tags: c#, wcf

I have problem with service "default" page. I have created service, as usual, and cannot get it to work.

Default service page does not show. It shows:

> Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

When I click on help page link, normal help page with listed operations shows.

What is wrong with my config?

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="PromoCenyParseService.PromoCenyParseService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://xxxxxxx.ovh.net:7741/PromoCenyParseService.svc" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="PromoCenyParseService.IPromoCenyParseService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you posted serviceContract and operationContract attribute on the interface for the service ?

Comment: Have you tried to access your services with [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx)? 
Go to: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe" (change path to your own version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that problem by adding baseAddress to my service like that:

```
  <service name="PromoCenyParseService.PromoCenyParseService" 
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://xxxxxxx.ovh.net:7741/PromoCenyParseService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="PromoCenyParseService.IPromoCenyParseService" />
  </service>
```